# Windows 7 random freezes

Tags: windows-7, freeze

My Desktop Computer with a Windows 7 64bit System freezes randomly an estimated 1-2 times a day, depending on the usage. The moment it freezes, nothing works anymore. I can´t move the mouse, use CTRL-ALT-DEL or anything similar and have to reboot the computer. As I’m doing my work on it, that is unacceptable.

System Specs:

- AMD FX 4100 Quad Core
- Motherboard: ASRock Extreme3 R2.0
- Windows 7 64 bit (fresh install)
- DirectX 11
- 8GB RAM (2x Kingston KVR1333D3N9/4G)
- NVidia GeForce GTX 560 Ti
- Main Programs installed: SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2012, Office 2013, Adobe Acrobat

I´ve been having this problem for over a month now and can´t find the error. What I´ve done up to now:

- Fresh Windows 7 64bit install
- Updated BIOS to latest Version
- Exchanged both RAM-sticks with new DDR3 RAM (2x Micron
  MT8JTF51264AZ-1G6)
- Changed the BIOS settings for the RAM-sticks to manual, according to
  the settings suggested by motherboard manufacturer
- Updated the GeForce driver
- Updated LAN-, USB- and audio-drivers
- Checked the Windows error-log and found nothing relevant (Event-ID
  41, Category-ID 63 = System rebooted unexpectedly; Event-ID 6008 =
  system was unexpectedly shut down)

I think that was it and I haven’t missed out on anything. My system is still freezing randomly. I bought the computer a year ago and experienced no problems until I reinstalled a fresh copy of Windows 7 on my main partition. All problems have occurred since then.

Have I missed out on anything? I would greatly appreciate any help, as this error is turning out to be very annoying and time consuming.

Comment: This has nothing to do with systems adminstration, and will likely be moved/closed.

Comment: I would almost put money on it being a HDD problem.

Comment: @Chris, I have Windows 7 x64 running on a Corsiar Gen 4 SSD and all files stored on sata 3 raid array with crossfired 5850s. My system randomly freezes as well. I didn't have the issue with Windows x86, but only when I switched to x64. I too have tried everything in the book without resolve. You may just have to chalk this up as an OS issue and live it, else move back to x86. Reformating and reinstalling doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Chris, I just noticed this, but I should mention that I also have the ASRock Extreme3 870 R2.0. and 8gb Kingston RAM. Purhaps that's the key.

Comment: @Ramhound: It is not a HD problem. I have checked the disk for errors and didn´t find anything...

Comment: @JoshCampbell: Hmm, maybe it´s the motherboard? It can´t be the RAM, as I´ve exchanged it completely and the system still freezes. I´ve only been having this problem for a few months. Everything was fine before - even on a Windows 7 64bit system. I far as I can recall, the freezes started after doing a fresh install. Any other idea what could cause them? This is really frustating - as you will also have experienced...

Comment: @Chris, I know it's not the RAM, Just thought it was interesting that our systems were so close, so I threw it out there. Unforntunately, I gave up on the issue after running out of ideas. After trying a fresh instal I turned off automatic updates & limited what Microsoft installed on my machine. I went to absolute basics; not even Areo and themes are turned on- Everything is plain Jane. The issue still persists. If I had to make an educated guess, I would say it has something to do with Win 7x64 and our board. Just out of curiousity.. are you running Chrome?

Comment: You said that it hangs 1 -2 times a day, depending on the usage. Can you explain more. What usage? What program? Is there any pattern? If it freezes more often the more you use it then it implies an over heating issue but most likely, it's hardware

Comment: @Josh Campbell: Yes, normally I´d say it´s the motherboard too, but I had Windows 7 64bit working for nearly a year without an issue. The issues came up when I made a fresh install. Also, I was suspecting SQL-Server or Visual Studio to be involved in the freezes, but I´ve also updated both from SQL-Server 2010 to 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 to 2012 (Microsoft Action Pack). I don´t really think it could be anything involving those programs now. I also updated Office from 2010 to 2013 with the last fresh install. I need a Windows 64bit Version, as it allows more than 4GB RAM.

Comment: @DaveRook: I have the feeling that the system tends to freeze when I start working: I use SQL-Server and Visual Studio a lot. They seem to be connected to the issue somehow. Also Firefox might be involved. Read my previous post to Josh Campbell: Updated all programs also. There is no recognizable pattern to the freezes. It isn't an overheating issue. Temperatures are fine, also no dust whatsoever on the fans. Everything is fine concerning that. I'm starting to suspect the motherboard, but I had Win7 64bit running without issues for about a year before I installed a fresh system...

Comment: @Chris - then doesn't it suggest something went wrong with the fresh installation of the OS? VS and SQL can have many issues with firewalls... maybe disable your AV and firewall (if safe to do so) just to test the water?

Comment: @DaveRook: Yes, it does. I just can't seem to find the the issue there though. Fresh install, all drivers up to date, newest BIOS for the board, all programs up to date, exchanged RAM, graphics driver up to date,... What else could it be?

Comment: But, if the OS has an issue else where... You can't fix a broken program  by just updating other areas... This is hacking! :) Same as your IT issue IMO. Try disabling the firewall since there are many issues in regards to firewall... Or, may be just re-install VS/SQL

Comment: I've disabled firewall now and will wait until next freeze :-) As of VS and SQL: It´s the second time I`ve reinstalled the system within a month or so, always installing a fresh copy of VS AND SQL (first 2010 and then on second install 2012). Do you really think it could be that? Reinstalling both programs would take several hours...

Comment: What tool did you use to determine it wasn't the hdd

Comment: @Chris, Are you using an SSD for the OS? If so, what make and model?

Comment: @JoshCampbell: No, it´s a normal HDD 1TB from Western Digital...

Comment: @Chris, did you ever find what was the culprit? I'm dealing with a very similar issue and it's driving me insane.

Comment: @Mahn, sorry, I can´t help you on that one: I can recall that I had the whole computer checked intensively without a result. No idea if it was hardware or a software issue. It may have been Windows 7 in combination with certain hardware components. In the end I just removed Windows 7, installed Windows 8 (no freezing problems, but it still could have been another software issue) and sold the computer... Good luck!

Comment: @Chris I see, okay, thank you for replying either way. Guess I'll have to look for a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I would check using a SMART tool the condition of your hard drive.

I would also look to see what programs are running and may use MSCONFIG to remove what is not necessary. This may result in at least narrowing it down to a software issue.

Make sure Task Scheduler is not doing anything at funny times!

Remove your machine from the network for a while to see if it due to an update (or some network activity).

It could be faulting RAM (although I would suspect this to result in a BSOD). It could be the CPU...

Do a system repair using the original Windows DVD.

If the system was OK but only recently playing up, think about what changes you made. Either roll back (system restore) or uninstall the drivers/software etc to see if that resolves the issue.

Either way, make sure you are backing up!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I Checked using a SMART Tool: Everything is fine. Maybe the LOG will show up something when the computer freezes the next time. Task Scheduler is doing nothing it shouldn't do. Removing machine from network might be an option - I'll try that out. It cannot be faulty RAM, as I have exchanged the RAM with freshly bought RAM. Why should I repair the system if it´s a fresh install? I don't see the point there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the screen BSOD or not? Are all Window Updates up to date?

Comment: No, the system freezes. No, mouse freezes, Ctrl+Alt+Del not possible - I need a hard reset when it happens. All Windows Updates are up to date...

Comment: @Chris, when this happens, does the lights and fans remain on/spinning? What PSU are you using? I know you said temps are fine, but not sure what temps you monitored; Can you search for a program which measures your CPU and GPU temperatures and monitor it please.

Comment: Lights and fans remain on and spinning. I'll have to monitor the temperatures, but I don't think it has something to do with that. Strangely enough I don´t get any freezes when I play games and temperatures rise. I can´t recall a crash whilst playing a game, e.g. Skyrim, Grid 2, Battlefield 3, ...

Comment: OK, well VS and SQL have firewall relationships, they both have network relationships and both can be resource intensive.. Again, I'd have to re-install them both to see if it's just the program(s)

Comment: Hmmm, if I think about it, that might be true. I put up the fresh system last Friday and it didn#t crash until Monday when I started working with VS and SQL server again as far as I can recall. I think I´ll have to try that then *grmpf*. What exactly would you suggest? Deinstalling both and then reinstalling them straight away?

Comment: Yes, un-install both and then re-install (And sorry to keep going on about firewalls but, make sure it is off during installation (this site has many questions about why it won't install and firewall is a frequent reason).

Comment: ...and thanks for helping out intensively! Unfortunately I can´t upvote on SuperUser yet, otherwise I would :-)

Comment: Haha, thanks again. I have one more issue I just recalled: Sometimes the system doesn't freeze at once: The mouse can´t be moved for a few seconds then and following that the mouse pointer is not displayed correctly. It looks like the pixels are messed up. Also I have two screens and can´t move the mouse to the second screen then. I can move the mouse and use the computer normally for a few minutes and the process repeats until a few minutes later the system freezes completely. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Chris, you'll need to ask a new question for that, however, let's get this first issue solved (in case they are *somehow* related)

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in safe mode for a few hours see if it freezes, it could indicate it's software as its obviously running on minimal services etc when in safe mode.

Play around with the  Restart on System Crash in System Properties > Advanced setting, it might allow you to see a/the blue screen instead of locking up when allowed to crash or restart.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changing the system properties as you suggested doesn't work. There is no option that handles freezing. Running the system in safe mode for a few hours could be quite interesting. I´ll have a go at that...

Comment: I remembered now when this was happening to me on an older machine, it was the GPU, no symptoms whatsoever I had to try a different GPU to notice. Check if your motherboard has blown capacitors.

Comment: How do I check that? I stated in another comment, that my GPU seems to be working fine, as I don´t have problems when playing games. I don´t experience crashes whilst playing (e.g. Battlefield 3, Skyrim, Grid 2,...). Those are graphical intense games.

Comment: Ah ok then about the GPU. About the mobo that was a separate note, open the case and have a hard look at it, check the connectors for HDDs etc as well, experiment with plugging HDs in different sata/ide what have you ports.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the bad capacitator issue. It yields completely random freezing.

http://www.badcaps.net/pages.php?vid=5

Answer (score 0):

Change HDD Sata cable and clean cpu cooling system. 
If that doesn't work then do the following:

1. Open Documents then double click on computer (left hand side bottom of screen).
2. Put cursor on Local disk C and RIGHT CLICK, then go down and click on properties.
3. A new window will open. At the top click on tools then click on Check now.
4. Another window will open, TICK both options then click on start.
5. A warning window will come up saying *it can't be done as the disk is in use but would you like to do the task when you restart your pc next time?*
6. Click yes then restart your computer.
7. While the computer is rebooting DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING AT ALL. It will take the PC 20-30 mins to reboot but it will clear all errors and fix all problems.

Hope this will help.